# binding event handlers in react boilerplate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-boilerplate

There are 4 methods for binding event handlers that i know. The first one is by binding within the DOM element in `render()`:

```
<button onClick = {this.clickHandler.bind(this)}>Event</button>
```

The second one is using an arrow function within the DOM element in `render()`:

```
<button onClick = {() => this.clickHandler()}>Event</button>
```

The third one is by binding within the class constuctor:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
             message: "Click"
        }
        **this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);**
    }
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>{this.state.message}</div>
                **<button onClick = {this.clickHandler}>Event</button>**
            </div>
        )
    }
```

The forth way is by changing the class property to an arrow function:

```
clickHandler = () => {
        this.setState({
            message: 'Goodbye!'
        })
    }
```

So which way is best?

Comment: What are your objective metrics for "best"?

Comment: @TylerH My intent is to find out which method is optimal for synchronous processing and is fastest to develop with

Answer (score 1):

From what I know :-

- In **1st** case, a newly **bound** `clickHandler` will be created on every **render** of your React app.
- In **2nd** case, a new **anonymous arrow function** will be created which internally calls the `clickHandler` (on-execution) on every **render** of your React app.
- Both **3rd and 4th** are better since they cause one-time creation of the `clickHandler`. They are outside the **render** flow.

Comment: Which between 3rd and 4th would you say is fastest on compilation and execution?

Comment: That really boils down to arrow function vs regular function performance. I haven’t explored that. I think arrow function is what I would like to go with since I am even skipping the creation of one-time bound function. But not really sure how much of a performance gain would that be.